# index.html for Azure Mobile Apps

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services

I have an index.html page for my [Azure Mobile app](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/app-service/mobile/) that I want to use instead of the default blue web page that shows "This mobile app is up and running".  I put the index.html in the wwwroot folder and set the homePage value to false in app.js

```
var mobile = azureMobileApps({
   // Explicitly enable the Azure Mobile Apps home page
    homePage: false
});
```

but the page is not served up.  I get a blank page with this text instead

```
Cannot GET /
```

What else do I need to do in order to have my mobile app serve static HTML & JS pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the code in app.js with below one.

1. You need to tell server to use static files from specific folder ( here public ). Place you index file inside the public folder.
2. Then you need to return the file when root of the application is called.

   ```
   mobileApp.tables.initialize()
   .then(function () {
       app.use(mobileApp);    // Register the Azure Mobile Apps middleware
       app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);   // Listen for requests

       //Need to add below 2 lines
       app.use(express.static('public'));
       app.get('/',function(req,res){
         res.sendFile('index.html');
       });
   });
   ```